# Accessing strings.xml values in android library project

Tags: android

I have MyAppProject as android application project and MyLibProject as android library project.
I have strings.xml(2 strings) and one xyz.java class in MyLibProject.
xyz.java class has 2 get methods to access the strings.xml values.

I have added reference library project "MyLibProject" in "MyAppProject" application project.

For some usecase, I will check whether Library project xyz.java class is in classpath then get the 
values from xyz.class.

How to access the strings.xml texts in xyz.java class get method?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you should be able to access any references via a fully qualified name for the R file you're attempting to access, via the `Context`. Something like (untested):

```
Context.getString(com.YOUR.LIB.R.string.YOURSTRING));
```

Failing that, you could possibly import the `com.YOUR.LIB.R` file directly into your activity.

Hope this helps! And I hope that I understand what you're trying to achieve. If not, please provide more information and possibly some code you've already tried, may help explain your problem :)

Comment: I have simple class in my library project.I dont have any activity class and i dont have context.Is there anyway to achive the above issue without context?

Comment: You have no activity at all? Not even in your main application? If so, what is the purpose of using strings.xml, over just in code references with getters/setters? I'm a little confused as to where you're actually attempting to reference these values from.

Comment: i dont have activity in library project.In main application i have.I am using strings.xml for internalization(Globalization) purpose.

Comment: I tried creating one App class which extends android Application class.And tried to get the context in App class and it is null.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been very old, but creating Android libraries will never get old. I have been working on creating Android libraries for a few days now, and myself encountered this issue of not been able to use `res` directory resources in library's java files due to some reason. After 2 days of searching, I found that I was missing package declaration in my library's manifest file.

So, to make it working, check if you have declared package in manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yourpackage">

</manifest>
```

It worked for me after this change, now I can use resources in library's java files. I hope it works for you too.